# MySQL Query to Find Balance from Sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transaction table like the following:

```
debit_amount         to_be_collect  
5.00                 56.48  
100.00               0.00   
30.00                143.97
```

Need to get the result as sum of to_be_collect - debit amount like ledger account.Expecting result set as follows

```
  debit_amount       to_be_collect                   balance
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  5.00               56.48             195.45(sum of to_be_collect - debit)
  100.00             0.00              95.45 (195.45 - 100)
  30.00              143.97            65.45 (95.45 - 30)
```

Is it possible to get the result from query or do i use stored procedure for this? Please help.

Comment: Is the value 143.97 the same with the value in the result which is 43.97 due to typography error?And how did you come up with 95.45. I don't get it. Please explain further.

Comment: How are we supposed to understand how the rows are ordered? (You say you want "result of frist row - debit"...)

Comment: i have edited my question.Kindly please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use user-defined variables for this. Read more about them [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html).

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (id int auto_increment primary key, `debit_amount` numeric(5,2), `to_be_collect` numeric(5,2))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`debit_amount`, `to_be_collect`)
VALUES
    (5.00, 56.48),
    (100.00, 0.00),
    (30.00, 143.97)
;
```

Query:

```
select
t.*,
@balance := @balance - debit_amount as balance
from
t
, (select @balance := sum(to_be_collect) from t) var_init_subquery
order by id
```

Result:

```
| ID | DEBIT_AMOUNT | TO_BE_COLLECT | BALANCE |
|----|--------------|---------------|---------|
|  1 |            5 |         56.48 |  195.45 |
|  2 |          100 |             0 |   95.45 |
|  3 |           30 |        143.97 |   65.45 |
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/553df/1/0)